# Diamond inheritance in Python with different signatures

Tags: python, multiple-inheritance, diamond-problem

Here's the setup:

```
class Player(object):
    def __init__(self, heigth):
        self.heigth = heigth
        print('do not forget that this should happen once!')

class Attacker(Player):
    def __init__(self, heigth, goal_probability):
        super().__init__(heigth)
        self.goal_prob = goal_probability

    def hit(self):
        pass
        # implementation

class Goalie(Player):
    def __init__(self, heigth, save_probability=0.1):
        super().__init__(heigth)
        self.save_prob = save_probability

    def catch(self):
        pass
        # implementation

class UniversalPlayer(Attacker, Goalie):
    pass

up = UniversalPlayer(heigth=1.96, goal_probability=0.6)
```

It all works as expected: the MRO chooses `Attacker` first, then `Goalie`. I call `UniversalPlayer`'s constructor with `Attacker`'s `__init__` signature, `Goalie`'s constructor is called with `Player`'s signature, it goes ok because `save_probability` has a default value but **the problem is that I have no way of choosing `save_probability`,** apart from setting `up.save_probability` after instantiating `up`, which I find very inelegant.

Furthermore, had `Goalie` not had a default value for `save_probability`, this code would raise an exception.

Is there a way to write `UniversalPlayer` so that I can choose `save_probability` too, or is there some fundamental problem here that cannot be worked around?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each additional parameter to `__init__` needs to have a class responsible for removing it from calls to `super`, so that when `object.__init__` is finally called, you don't accidentally pass any arguments to it. Additionally, each method has to accept arbitrary arguments and pass them on for the next method to possibly handle.

```
# Player will be responsible for height
class Player(object):
    def __init__(self, height, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)  # Player needs to use super too!
        self.height = height
        print('do not forget that this should happen once!')


# Attacker will be responsible for goal_probability
class Attacker(Player):
    def __init__(self, height, goal_probability, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(height, **kwargs)
        self.goal_prob = goal_probability

    def hit(self):
        pass


# Goalie will be responsible for save_probability
class Goalie(Player):
    def __init__(self, height, save_probability=0.1, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(height, **kwargs)
        self.save_prob = save_probability

    def catch(self):
        pass
        # implementation

class UniversalPlayer(Attacker, Goalie):
    pass

# Pass all arguments
# Life is easier if you stick to keyword arguments when using super().__init__
up = UniversalPlayer(height=1.96, goal_probability=0.6, save_probability=0.2)
```

Now, `Attacker.__init__` is the first to be called. It uses `goal_probability`, then does not pass it on to other calls. It accepts `save_probability` via `**kwargs` and passes it on for `Goalie.__init__` to eventually receive. Note that neither `Attacker.__init__` nor `Goalie.__init__` would have to explicitly include `height` in their argument lists; it could also be accepted via `**kwargs` to be eventually received by `Player.__init__`.

Comment: Nice and elegant. Thank you!

Comment: This is all essentially lifted from https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the fact I'm not sure if separate classes is the best way to handle these, the issue is that your constructors can't handle unknown arguments. To allow them to use the `*args, **kwargs` notation. 
Effectively all arguments will be passed to each `__init__` and the unused ones ignored.

```
class Player(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.height = kwargs['height']

class Attacker(Player):
    def __init__(self, goal_probability, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.goal_prob = goal_probability

    def hit(self):
        pass
        # implementation

class Goalie(Player):
    def __init__(self, save_probability, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.save_prob = save_probability

    def catch(self):
        pass
        # implementation

class UniversalPlayer(Attacker, Goalie):
    pass

up = UniversalPlayer(height=1.96, goal_probability=0.6, save_probability=0.2)
```